# Цвет постепенно исчезает с обеих сторон div

Tags: html, css, градиент

Мне нужно создать полосу с исчезновением цвета на каждой стороне div, как показано на рисунке ниже, используя CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/28982198/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не планируется поддержка старых браузеров, то `linear-gradient` - лучшее решение:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/hPLqUtN.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #D4D4CC 100px, #D4D4CC calc(100% - 100px), transparent);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Да, смотрится классно. Просто и со вкусом.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: а я вот про обёртку и `box-shadow` даже и не подумал бы. А плюс в твоём решении - поддержка IE9. Привет, Саш.

Answer (score 4):

### Над плоскостью

Чтобы сделать затухающий цвет с обеих сторон, вы можете использовать два inset [box-shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)  с положительным размытием и отрицательным радиусом распространения:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/uqpLh809/)

```css
body {
  background: #D4D4CC;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0px 100px -50px #D4D4CC, 
              inset -100px 0px 100px -50px #D4D4CC;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Над изображением:

Если вам нужно растушевать обе стороны над изображением или не простым цветом, вы можете использовать этот подход с псевдоэлементом и box-shadow:

Output :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div{
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 100px;
    margin:20px;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    background:#D4D4CC;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px 50px #D4D4CC;
}

body{
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hPLqUtN.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Обратите внимание, что box-shadows поддерживаются [начиная с IE9](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)